# Создание новой строки в таблице. Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Я пытаюсь добавить новую строку в DOM. Есть инпуты Имя и Фамилия, и кнопка Добавить. При нажатии на кнопку должна добавиться новая строка в таблице. Работа над ошибками, не дает результатов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Имя</th>
        <th>Фамилия</th>
        <th>Удалить</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Иван</td>
        <td>Васильевич</td>
        <td class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Влад</td>
        <td>Анатольевич</td>
        <td class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form action="" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="" class="name" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <input type="text" name="" class="surname" placeholder="Введите фамилию">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Добавить строку</button>
</form>
```

Данный скрипт написал сам, более упрощая скрипт найденный в интернете. Но он не работает как я и предпологал. Мне сейчас важно понять как все работает, вроде сделал все по закону. Второй день уже сижу с этой задачей. Если есть варианты, накиньте идеи, пожалуйста.

```
var table = document.querySelector('.table');
table.addEventListener('click', checkAct);

function checkAct(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'TD' && event.target.className !== 'delete') {
        editTd(event.target);
    } else if ((event.target.classList.contains('fa-trash')) === true) {
        event.target.closest('tr').remove();
    }
}

function editTd(target) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = target.innerHTML;
    target.innerHTML = '';
    target.appendChild(input);
    input.addEventListener('keypress',addChanges);
}

function addChanges(event) {
    var newCreateInput = event.target;
    var parent = newCreateInput.parentNode;
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        parent.innerHTML = newCreateInput.value;
    }
}

var inputName = document.querySelector('.name');
var inputSurname = document.querySelector('.surname');
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');

function definitionsName(name) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = name.value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

function definitionsSurname(surname) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = surname.value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

btn.addEventListener('click',addTr);

function addTr() {
    if (inputName.value === '' || inputSurname.value === '') {
        return alert('Заполните поля Имя и Фамилия');
    }
    definitionsName(name);
    definitionsSurname(surname);
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var i = document.createElement('i');
    i.classList.add('fa fa-trash');
    td.appendChild(i);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: А как он не работает? В чем ошибка? Опишите ошибку подробно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скопировал код к себе, несколько поправил, вот что получилось:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Имя</th>
        <th>Фамилия</th>
        <th>Удалить</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Иван</td>
        <td>Васильевич</td>
        <td class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Влад</td>
        <td>Анатольевич</td>
        <td class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form action="" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="" class="name" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <input type="text" name="" class="surname" placeholder="Введите фамилию">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Добавить строку</button>
</form>
 <script>
var table = document.querySelector('.table');
table.addEventListener('click', checkAct);

function checkAct(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'TD' && event.target.className !== 'delete') {
        editTd(event.target);
    } else if ((event.target.classList.contains('fa-trash')) === true) {
        event.target.closest('tr').remove();
    }
}

function editTd(target) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = target.innerHTML;
    target.innerHTML = '';
    target.appendChild(input);
    input.addEventListener('keypress',addChanges);
}

function addChanges(event) {
    var newCreateInput = event.target;
    var parent = newCreateInput.parentNode;
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        parent.innerHTML = newCreateInput.value;
    }
}

var inputName = document.querySelector('.name');
var inputSurname = document.querySelector('.surname');
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');

function definitionsName(name) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = name.value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

function definitionsSurname(surname) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = surname.value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

btn.addEventListener('click',addTr);

function addTr(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (inputName.value === '' || inputSurname.value === '') {
        return alert('Заполните поля Имя и Фамилия');
    }
    definitionsName(inputName);
    definitionsSurname(inputSurname);
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var i = document.createElement('i');
    i.classList.add('fa');
    i.classList.add('fa-trash');
    td.appendChild(i);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Вообще он есть, в начале кода, и он объявлен глобально! Сейчас отредактирую js скрипт, выложу весь код.

Comment: Так а что dev tools консоль говорит?

Comment: Попробовал у себя, там 5-6 изменений примерно пришлось сделать чтоб заработало.

Comment: Вначале выдал что name и surname is not diefined. Поменял названия переменных на корректные. Честно говоря я вообще дев тулы не использовал, так что не знаю что дальше, ошибок больше нету никаких. Вот чувствую что где-то некрасиво написано но не знаю где :(

Comment: в функции addTr, вызов функций идет:
definitionsName(name);
definitionsSurname(surname);
name & surname тут не определены раньше, определены inputName & inputSurname

Comment: Как я понял данные две функции function definitionsName(name) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = name.value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

function definitionsSurname(surname) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = surname.value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
}

Comment: Просто объявляют что теперь могут создавать td-шки, у них в аргументах написано name и surname просто для определения и для будущей ставки inputName и inputSurname. Прав ли я? И еще можете немножко описать про event.preventDefault(), что он тут делает?

Comment: нет,
var td = document.createElement('td'); - непосредственно создает в документе новый элемент <td></td>
 td.innerHTML = surname.value; -- заполняет внутренний HTML нового тега, указанным значением (тут surname.value, surname - прилетает в функцию из вне)
tr.appendChild(td); -- добавляет в tr (который ранее был объявлен), созданные елемент td. Он не определяет что может делать, а создает элемент и переносит его в tr. А name & surname используется для заполнения текстом этому элементу.

Comment: event.preventDefault() - прекращает событие по умолчанию. Кнопка submit в форме - по умолчанию отправляет данные на форму, даже если в action ничего не указать - это текущая страница. preventDefault()  - отменяет это действите по умолчанию. Иначе (без этой кнопки), страница будет перезагружаться.

Comment: Cпасибо Вам большое за помощь. Про event.preventDefault() я еще почитаю, уверен как нибудь дойду до истины.